# Implementing slide down animation with "Element.animate()" method

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I tried to implement the slide down animation by [`Element.animate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate):

```js
errorsMessagesCollapsableContainerMountingPoint.replaceWith(errorsMessagesCollapsableContainer);

errorsMessagesCollapsableContainer.animate(
  [
    { height: 0, overflow: "hidden" },
    { height: "auto", overflow: "visible" }
  ],
  {
    duration: 2000
  }
);
```

but it is not smooth:

[image]

Something that I missing in Animation API usage?

The HTML of errors list is just `<ul><li>...</li></ul>`.

### Update

From [this post](https://dzone.com/articles/pure-css-slide-down-animation-1), I knew that animation works only numeric amounts.
I replaces my code with:

```js
// The `clientHeight` could not be retrieved without being mounted
errorsMessagesCollapsableContainer.style.overflow = "hidden";
errorsMessagesCollapsableContainer.style.visibility = "hidden";
errorsMessagesCollapsableContainer.style.position = "absolute";

errorsMessagesCollapsableContainerMountingPoint.replaceWith(this.#errorsMessagesCollapsableContainer);

const errorsMessagesCollapsableContainerHeight: number = errorsMessagesCollapsableContainer.clientHeight;


errorsMessagesCollapsableContainer.style.visibility = "visible";
errorsMessagesCollapsableContainer.style.position = "static";


this.#errorsMessagesCollapsableContainer.animate(
  [
    { height: 0 },
    { height: errorsMessagesCollapsableContainerHeight }
  ],
  2000
);
```

but animation still not smooth.

Please not that this question is focused on pure JavaScript `Element.animate()` solution, not CSS animation or third-party solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your picture you have  ( duration: 2000 ) works as a delay, not the duration of the animation. Try simply applying transition to this class in the styles

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Because this answer is focused on `Element.animate()"`, not pure CSS animations, would you please to add the `Element.animate()"` solution?